# Apache Airflow: Delay start parallel tasks in Single DAG to avoid "ConcurrentAppend" Error in Redshift

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I want start some parallel tasks in single DAG with some delay in start time to avoid "ConcurrentAppend" error in Redshift, Yes we can do some work around in Redshift Target Table to avoid this but in my case it is different. Please help me out to solve this issue.(All tasks writing the o/p in same table with different where condition)

```
            --> Task 1A (Starts at 0s)                       --> Task 1B
```

Start_Pipeline  --> Task 2A (Starts at 300s after Task1A started)--> Task 2B

```
            --> Task 3A (Starts at 300s after Task2A started)--> Task 3B
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [pool](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#pools) with 1 slot then assign those parallel tasks to that pool. It will force them to run sequentially and avoid `ConcurrentAppend`.

```
pool X with 1 slot


      / - [task 1A, pool X] - [task 1B, no pool]
start - - [task 2A, pool X] - [task 2B, no pool]
      \ - [task 3A, pool X] - [task 3B, no pool]

task A will run sequentially
task B will run after task A
```